# Strange behaviour of keywords within macros in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, macros, keyword

I'm a little confused by how keyword accesses seem to behave in Clojure when they are evaluated at macro expansion time.

The following works as I expect:

```
(def m {:a 1})
(:a m)
=> 1
```

However the same keyword access doesn't seem to work within a macro:

```
(def m {:a 1})
(defmacro get-a [x] (:a x))
(get-a m)
=> nil
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should take into account that macro's don't evaluate their arguments, unless you tell them so. In your version, get-a gets a symbol m and the result isn't code, it is keyword :a looking itself up in a symbol, which is obviously nil. This works however:

```
(defmacro get-a [x] `(:a ~x))
```

The result of calling this macro with argument m is the expression '(:a m)', which evaluates to 1 in your context.

Comment: OK - so if you want to have the macro expand to just "1" rather than "(:a m)" how would you do that? I'm interested in how you get the keyword lookup to happen at macro expansion time rather than later if that makes sense.....

Comment: If you really want to do that, you can use eval:

(defmacro get-a [x]
  (:a (eval x))), but if that is all you need, a function is way more appropriate here.

Comment: Cool - that works perfectly! Many thanks! Seems like what I needed to do was evaluate the symbol. I'm actually trying to do something much more complicated with macros but this particular behaviour was tripping me up :-)